# Separator bars in StatusBar have unequal width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The separator bars between each TextBlock in the StatusBar appear to have unequal widths. Some bars appear thinner than others. The first and fourth bar from the left appear thicker than the second and third. I'd appreciate if anyone could offer any solutions for equal width separators.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File" Name="menuFile"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Height="20">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Text="txt1"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="1"/>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Text="txt2"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="3"/>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
            <TextBlock Text="txt3"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="5"/>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="6">
            <ProgressBar Value="30" Width="100" Height="20" Padding="5,0"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <Separator Grid.Column="7"/>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="8">
            <Label Name="lblTime" Content="Time" Padding="5,0"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

[image: first separator thicker than second]

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of the issue ??

Comment: Interestingly, after installing Visual Studio 15.5.1 and running it, I no longer see the issue. My other computer at home is running the previous version of visual studio 2017. I'll try re-running the project on that computer. Stay tuned...

Comment: Checked version 15.4.5 and doesn't have the issue either. Not really sure what happened.

Comment: I guess there was a glitch in the Matrix.

Comment: Problem acted up again. Screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. I added margins

```
<Separator Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0,2"></Separator>
```

and it seemed to work. 
However if I added the SAME margins to the second separator I ended up with the problem with that one. So I left that one alone